# I can't connect to snowflake using node js connector

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to connect to snowflake database, using `snowflake-sdk` connector.

First I installed the `snowflake-sdk`, using the command line:

```
npm install snowflake-sdk
```

After I followed all the instructions reported [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html).

i created the file `index.js` containing:

```
    var snowflake = require('snowflake-sdk');
    var connection = snowflake.createConnection( {
        account : 'xxxx.east-us-2'
        username: 'MYUSERNAME'
        password: 'MYPASSWORD'
        }
        );
    connection.connect( 
        function(err, conn) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
                } 
            else {
                console.log('Successfully connected to Snowflake.');            
                }
            }
        );
```

and after I run  the command `node index.js`

and I had the Connection error:

> Unable to connect: Network error. Could not reach Snowflake.

I Tried again, changing the account value in `xxxx.east-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com` but nothing changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your account name should include cloud provider as well. 
Change the account name as :

```
var connection = snowflake.createConnection( {
    account : 'xxxx.east-us-2.azure'
    username: 'MYUSERNAME'
    password: 'MYPASSWORD'
    }
```

For full account names refer [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html#required-connection-options)

Comment: It works!!!! Thank you!! i missed ".azure" on account name...

Comment: Am using this config, still getting  "Unable to connect: Network error. Could not reach Snowflake."

url ::: xxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com

const connection = snowflake.createConnection({
      account: 'xxx.us-east-1.aws',
      username: 'xxx',
      password: 'xxx'
 });
Kindly suggest to fix this issue @Zonera

Comment: This code solves the issue - snowflake.configure({ insecureConnect: true }); https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-nodejs/issues/16

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your account name. Please pass your account name as `xxxx.east-us-2.azure`

Comment: Thank you! This is critical.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I used in a tiny issue reproduction that I sent to the Snowflake support people.

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const snowflake = require("snowflake-sdk");
const Q = require("q");
const SNOWFLAKE_HOST_SUFFIX = 'snowflakecomputing.com';    
const SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT = 'companyname';
function getSFConnection(connParams) {
    var d = Q.defer();
    let connection = snowflake.createConnection({
        account: connParams.account || SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT,
        username: connParams.user,
        password: connParams.password || '',
        database: connParams.name,
        warehouse: connParams.warehouse
    });
    connection.connect(function (err, conn) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
            d.reject(err);
        }
        else {
            console.info('Successfully connected as id: ' + connection.getId());
            connection.close = function () {
                return disconnectSF(connection);
            };
            d.resolve(connection);
        }
    });
    return d.promise;
}
```

and I used it like:

```
getSFConnection({ 
    user: 'username',
    account: 'companyname',
    password: 'password',
    name: '',
    warehouse: 'warehouse_name'
}).then...
```

upon reflection I wonder why I have the host suffix set, but am not using it.. but there it is.

Answer (score -1):

Following is the right config for `"snowflake-sdk": "^1.5.3"`

```
var connection = snowflake.createConnection({
    account: 'xxx.us-east-1',
    username: 'yourUsername',
    password: 'yourPassword',
});
```

Do not specify the region.

**region — Deprecated**  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html