# How to connect to snowflake using node.js

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect my API to snowflake, using the node.js driver found in the snowflake documentation https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html

```
const connection = snowflake.createConnection({
  account: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT,
  username: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD,
})

connection.connect((err, conn) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
  } 
  else {
    console.log('Successfully connected to Snowflake.');
    const connection_ID = conn.getId();
    return connection_ID
  }
});
```

However, I am getting this error:
`Unable to connect: Network error. Could not reach Snowflake.`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend double checking what you have for SNOWACCT
make sure it's set like the examples in
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html#required-connection-options

The next thing I'd do is try to see if I could get `SnowCD` installed on the host(client)
your node.js application is running from.  SnowCD should help you determine what http/https resources
you can't access, and then perhaps you can work with someone on your networking team to determine
why your access isn't allowed (proxies, VPC rules, etc.).
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html

If you cannot install SnowCD, you can try to emulate the things it does, for example:

- Execute `SELECT SYSTEM$WHITELIST();` or `SELECT SYSTEM$WHITELIST_PRIVATELINK();`
- for each link returned, make an http or https call to each like what is done in the following link and finding out the status code for each url.
  https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/65434455/1440712

Make sure your account is something like this `xxx.us-east-1`, region is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect a snowflake with node js, You must install

> "snowflake-sdk"

using npm. the below code will help you to access snowflake connection.

```
const snowflake = require('snowflake-sdk');       
   connection = snowflake.createConnection({
      "account": "your account",
      "username": "user name",
      "password": "password",
      "database": "snowflake db",
      "warehouse": "snowflake warehouse",
      "schema": "schema"
    });connection.connect(function (err, conn) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
    } else {
      console.log('Successfully connected as id: ' + connection.getId());
    }
  });
```